# Why won't my products li wrap around my image? I need them to wrap around my floated image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Thank you in advance for any help, this has me wanting to throw my computer across the room! I don't understand why my ul products li are not wrapping around an image I added. I think this would be a CSS solution but just in case, here's what I did in the php:

In my archive-product.php file I added:

```
    <?php if ( is_product_category() ) {
      if ( is_product_category( 'cubicles' ) ) {
      echo '<div class="cubicles"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/menu_cubicles.jpg"></div>';
     } ?>
```

And the styles attached to that are:

```
     body.archive .cubicles { 
        height: 347px;
        width: 220px; 
        float: right; 
        margin-right:0;
     }
```

Here is the live link: http://dev.arnoldsofficefurniture.com/product-category/cubicles

Since it's floated right and the ul products li are floated left, I don't get why they aren't wrapping. I also don't get why the li are not consistently lined up and getting pushed down, if they are all the same height. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Paulie_D - I added "I need them to wrap around my floated image" to the question. Is that OK?

Comment: Could we reproduce the issue with the code we have in the question? NO? Then that's what we need. If your dev link went away it would be on no use to future users.

Comment: Apologies if you feel that, it was not my intention but my original comment spelled everything out...it's a direct quote from the Stack Overflow guidelines on positing questions.

Comment: @antu Do you realize you mention having problems with wrapping images in an `li`, and yet your code example doesn't even have an `li`? What exactly do you expect people to help you with, if all you show is some php if statement and wonky css?

Comment: You may think that your dev site is useful but, in terms of future usefulness to other Stack Overflow users, it is not optimal. If the link goes away, the problem is not reproducible from the code you have provided. Also, it would require anyone who might wish to answer the question to inspect your HTML & CSS using developer tools rather than have that open to use in sandbox environments such as [**JSFiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [**Codepen.io**](http://codepen.io/) - Help us, help you and future users.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D, those are helpful. But as of right now, I don't see a way to add PHP in those? Those are for JS, HTML, and CSS. If I do a pastebin with my code would that help? You could only view it though, you couldn't mess with it live.

Comment: Why does it need to be PHP? The problem sounds like you can just copy the generated HTML out of the browser and put it in a snippet here.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lister! That is my cat's name! I named him after the Red Dwarf character. Anywho, the li's are 200px wide, and 4 would fit on a line until I added my image. For some reason even though the image and li's are floated, the li's are not wrapping back to 4 in a row under the image. Do you think grabbing the HTML will give the full picture? What if the issue is in the PHP?

Comment: @antu According to my DOM inspector, the `li`s are 220px wide, plus 30px for the margin, or 250px in total. The `main-wrapper` div is 975px wide, not enough to accommodate 4 `li`s in a row. Maybe you changed other things too, when you added the image?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not dropping under the cubicles area is because there isn't enough room.  The entire area for the products is 975px wide.  Each product list item is 220px plus 30px right margin.  Simple math... 250 * 4 = 1000.  If you remove the cubicle, you'll still only have three products per line.

You need to rework your width/margin-right to fix it.

Comment: I removed the cubicle pic and there is 4 on each line, as there were before. I don't know why, but that's how it was before and how it is again. I think I'm going to scrap the whole idea and try another way. I do appreciate everyone's input for future reference though!